# $scop.dologin() function does not returned json value after post method?

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform

I'm new in Ionic and angular and i'm creating a cross platform application in VS2015 using Ionic side menu template. i'm using WCF service to communicate with SQL Server.
I have 1) Controller.js and 2) services.js file

**My controller.js code is:**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, WCF_RESTService) {

  // Form data for the login modal
  $scope.loginData = {};

  // Create the login modal that we will use later
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  // Triggered in the login modal to close it
  $scope.closeLogin = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  // Open the login modal
  $scope.login = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
  $scope.doLogin = function() {
    console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData);
    //alert("start sign in...");

    var userdtl = {
        UserName: $scope.loginData.username,
        Password: $scope.loginData.password
    };  

    var UserId = WCF_RESTService.post(userdtl);       


    UserId.success(function (data) {
        //$scope.UserId = data;
        console.log(data);
    });


  };
})
```

---

**And My Services.js file code is:**

```
/// <reference path="../angular.min.js" />  
/// <reference path="Modules.js" />  
angular.module('starter.services', [])

//.factory('testFactory', function () {
//    return {
//        Hello: function () {
//            return "Hello World!";
//        }
//    }
//});

.service('WCF_RESTService', function ($http) {   

    //Create new record  
    this.post = function (UserInfo) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "http://10.0.0.98:10234/test.svc/verifieduser",
            data: UserInfo,           
        });           

        return request;
    }

});
```

---

$http url is hitting server successfully (checked in fiddler). but it doesnot show returned data. In controller it shows

```
 UserId.success(function (data) {
        //$scope.UserId = data;
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Error: "data is not recognized"

is there somthing missing or mistake in my code.

Comment: Does direct access to your API method (http://10.0.0.98:10234/test.svc/verifieduser) work?

Comment: currently working in local network and it accessing.